# Form working locally but not on Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, digital-ocean

Some reason this form worked locally, but now when I put the code on a Digital Ocean droplet the submit button no longer submits.. It doesn't do anything, and does not go to the controller. Not sure what's wrong. Code for partial is attached below:

```
<%= form_for(@amazon, url: amazon_index_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="col-md-12 well">  <!-- This is the first well, and says take 
  up all the 8 rows we have-->

<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Merchant Id</h4>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <div class="input-group-addon border">    
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
      <%= f.text_field :merchant_id, :placeholder => "Merchant Id", 
      class: "form-control input-group-lg", required: true %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <h4>
    Marketplace
  </h4>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <div class="input-group-addon border">    
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <%= f.select :marketplace, 
     grouped_options_for_select(marketplace_listing),
    {}, class: 'form-control input-group-lg' %>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <h4>MWS Auth Token</h4>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <div class="input-group-addon border">    
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
      <%= f.text_field :auth_token, hide_label: true,:placeholder => "MWS 
       Auth Token", 
      class: "form-control input-group-lg", required: true %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= f.submit 'Save Profile', class: 'btn btn-green btn-lg btn-block' %>
</div> <!--this is the well and takes up the 8 columns -->
<% end %>
```

I did just get this error in the console:

```
enteReferenceError: ShopifyApp is not defined
ShopifyApp.ready(function(){r code here
```

Comment: Are there some error message in the logs? Or maybe in the browser console? There's no way to know it the error message don't exist.

Comment: Arghh.. nothing.. no errors.. I think it has something to do with javascript..this is an embedded app in an iFrame.. but I don't know why its stopped working